# Error code PU5H on my older GE Adora Range

Tags: electrical, repair, replacement, troubleshooting, glass-top-range

Model Number    JBP730LASS
Brand   GE
Age More than 10 years

I have an older GE Adora series range. The broiler element went out and I ordered a new genuine GE element, and installed it. When I turned the breaker back on and tried the Broil function this code started flashing on the screen: PU5H. I also tried the Bake function and it gave the same code, but when I retried the Bake function it worked properly. I went out and turned off the breaker again, to see if this might reset the problem code. After a couple of minutes, I turned the breaker back on and tried the Broil function. I got the same code again. It would be helpful to know what this code is referring to so I could then troubleshoot the cause.

I have looked all over online and cannot find this specific code. Can anyone help or have any suggestions for what I should look at or try?? By the way, I believe I reconnected the wires to the broiler element correctly, but, if I was to have reversed the wires, would that cause a problem??

Thanks for any input!

Comment: All the GE error codes I've been able to find are 2-characters with `F` and a digit. Are you sure this isn't supposed to read `PUSH`, not `PU5H`? Maybe there's something you're supposed to "push" in order to complete a reset? `</SWAG>`